# How convert NSInputStream to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsinputstream, bytestream

I have an NSInputStream that I'm sending to server and while upload is going on, I want to display image that's uploading. Method is located in singleton and it's receiving that NSInputStream. Is there a way to read that stream and convert it to UIImage?

I've tried with this, but no luck. Where is my mistake?

```
var buffer = [UInt8](count:1024, repeatedValue: 0)
    thumbnailStream.open()
    if (thumbnailStream.hasBytesAvailable){
        let len : Int = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
        var pictureData = NSData(bytes: buffer, length: len)
        var imagess = UIImage(data: pictureData)!
        self.headerProgress.imageView.image = imagess
        print("Data of image = \(pictureData.length)")

        }else{
        print("No bytes")
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you used the debugger? What actually happens when you run the code you posted?

Comment: Variable `pictureData` has the length of the buffer count  `1024`. I've changed the value of the count and the length of the `pictureData` is changed to the value of the count and also the runtime fails and `pictureData` line of the code is highlighted. Also, I'm sure that I'm send the image data to this method because the media is successfully upload to the server. @rmaddy

Comment: You need to read all of the data from the input stream, not just the first 1024 bytes.

Comment: Is there a way to get the size of the stream? Because I cannot predict how many bytes the stream with the image has.

Comment: You have to loop until there's no more data.

Comment: Oh yeah, so while 'hasBytesAvailable' is true read the '1024' bytes. Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: I figured it out, it's working now. Do you want me to send the code so you can post the answer? Thanks for giving me idea.

Comment: If you think an answer will help others, feel free to post your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution to this issue and it's in working order.

```
    var count = 0
    let dataOfTheImage = NSMutableData()
    var buffer = [UInt8](count:1024, repeatedValue: 0)
    thumbnailStream.open()

    //MARK: Loop through thumbnail stream
    while (thumbnailStream.hasBytesAvailable){
        count = count + 1
        print("Counter: \(count)")
        //MARK: Read from the stream and append bytes to NSMutableData variable
        let len  = thumbnailStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
        dataOfTheImage.appendBytes(buffer, length: len)

        //MARK: Size of the image in MB
        let size = Float(dataOfTheImage.length) / 1024.0 / 1024.0
        print("Data length = \(size)")
    }

    //MARK: Check if there are no bytes left and show the image
    if (thumbnailStream.hasBytesAvailable == false){
        thumbnailStream.close()
       // var pictureData = NSData(bytes: buffer, length: len)
        let progressImage = UIImage(data: dataOfTheImage)!
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
            self.headerProgress.imageView.image = progressImage
        })
    }
```